# ConnectException: Connection refused when run mapreduce in Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, connection, resourcemanager, connection-refused

I set up Hadoop(2.6.0) with multi machines mode : 1 namenode + 3 datanodes. When I used command : start-all.sh, they (namenode, datanode, resource manager, node manager) worked ok. I checked it with jps command and result on each node were bellow:

NameNode :

> 7300 ResourceManager
>
> 6942 NameNode
>
> 7154 SecondaryNameNode

DataNodes:

> 3840 DataNode
>
> 3924 NodeManager

And I also uploaded sample text file on HDFS at: /user/hadoop/data/sample.txt. Absolutely no error at that moment.

But when I tried to run a mapreduce with hadoop example's jar :

> hadoop jar hadoop-mapreduce-examples-2.6.0.jar wordcount /user/hadoop/data/sample.txt /user/hadoop/output

I have this error:

```
15/04/08 03:31:26 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1428478232474_0001 running    in uber mode : false
15/04/08 03:31:26 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 0% reduce 0%
15/04/08 03:31:26 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1428478232474_0001 failed with     state FAILED due to: Application application_1428478232474_0001 failed 2 times due to Error launching appattempt_1428478232474_0001_000002. Got exception: java.net.ConnectException: Call From hadoop/127.0.0.1 to localhost:53245 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused; For more details see:  http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/ConnectionRefused
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.wrapWithMessage(NetUtils.java:791)
at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.wrapException(NetUtils.java:731)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1472)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1399)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:232)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy31.startContainers(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.api.impl.pb.client.ContainerManagementProtocolPBClientImpl.startContainers(ContainerManagementProtocolPBClientImpl.java:96)
at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.amlauncher.AMLauncher.launch(AMLauncher.java:119)
at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.amlauncher.AMLauncher.run(AMLauncher.java:254)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:739)
at org.apache.hadoop.net.SocketIOWithTimeout.connect(SocketIOWithTimeout.java:206)
at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.connect(NetUtils.java:530)
at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.connect(NetUtils.java:494)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.setupConnection(Client.java:607)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.setupIOstreams(Client.java:705)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.access$2800(Client.java:368)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.getConnection(Client.java:1521)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1438)
    ... 9 more Failing the application.
15/04/08 03:31:26 INFO mapreduce.Job: Counters: 0
```

About the configuration, sure that namenode can ssh to datanodes and vice versa without prompt password.I also dissabled IP6 and modified /etc/hosts file :

> 127.0.0.1       localhost hadoop
>
> 192.168.56.102  hadoop-nn
>
> 192.168.56.103  hadoop-dn1
>
> 192.168.56.104  hadoop-dn2
>
> 192.168.56.105  hadoop-dn3

I dont know why mapreduced can't run althought namenode and datanodes worked alright. I'm almost stucked at here, can you help me find the reason??

## Thank you

Edit : 
Here config in hdfs-site.xml (namenode):

```
<property>
    <name>dfs.namenode.name.dir</name>
    <value>file:///usr/local/hadoop/hadoop_stores/hdfs/namenode</value>
    <description>NameNode directory for namespace and transaction logs storage.</description>
</property>
<property>
    <name>dfs.replication</name>
    <value>3</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>dfs.permissions</name>
    <value>false</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>dfs.datanode.use.datanode.hostname</name>
    <value>false</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>dfs.namenode.datanode.registration.ip-hostname-check</name>
    <value>false</value>
</property>
<property>
     <name>dfs.namenode.http-address</name>
     <value>hadoop-nn:50070</value>
     <description>Your NameNode hostname for http access.</description>
</property>
<property>
     <name>dfs.namenode.secondary.http-address</name>
     <value>hadoop-nn:50090</value>
     <description>Your Secondary NameNode hostname for http access.</description>
</property>
```

In datanodes :

```
<property>
    <name>dfs.datanode.data.dir</name>
    <value>file:///usr/local/hadoop/hadoop_stores/hdfs/data/datanode</value>
    <description>DataNode directory</description>
</property>

<property>
    <name>dfs.replication</name>
    <value>3</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>dfs.permissions</name>
    <value>false</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>dfs.datanode.use.datanode.hostname</name>
    <value>false</value>
</property>
<property>
     <name>dfs.namenode.http-address</name>
     <value>hadoop-nn:50070</value>
     <description>Your NameNode hostname for http access.</description>
</property>
<property>
     <name>dfs.namenode.secondary.http-address</name>
     <value>hadoop-nn:50090</value>
     <description>Your Secondary NameNode hostname for http access.</description>
```

Here's result with command : **hadoop fs -ls /user/hadoop/data**

> hadoop@hadoop:~/DATA$ hadoop fs -ls /user/hadoop/data 15/04/09 00:23:27 
>   Found 2 items
>
> -rw-r--r--   3 hadoop supergroup         29 2015-04-09 00:22 >/user/hadoop/data/sample.txt
>
> -rw-r--r--   3 hadoop supergroup         27 2015-04-09 00:22 >/user/hadoop/data/sample1.txt

**hadoop fs -ls /user/hadoop/output**

> ls: `/user/hadoop/output': No such file or directory

Comment: Did you format your `namenode` first? Also is there a line with `127.0.1.1` in your `/etc/hosts` file?

Comment: yep, I've format the namenode and the log show no errors.  do we need 127.0.1.1 in hosts file after line 127.0.0.1 too?

Comment: `127.0.1.1` is not needed since it causes connection issues mostly. Can you post your `hdfs-site.xml`?

Comment: yep, in hosts file no line 127.0.1.1. I added hdfs-site.xml's content in question . do you need anything else? I'm totally stucked with this T_T

Comment: What does this command results: `telnet hadoop-nn` in namenode and datanodes? Can you do `telnet 127.0.0.1` from your namenode?

Comment: Ooops, the result is : telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused. it's also with 127.0.0.1

Comment: But if connection refused, why I can upload file to HDFS, its blocks are available in 3 datanodes.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74782/discussion-between-kate-and-rajesh-n).

Comment: `telnet 127.0.0.1` should work. I will come to it later. Post the results for: `hadoop fs -ls /user/hadoop/data` and `hadoop fs -ls /user/hadoop/output`

Comment: I updated result in the question. With hadoop fs -ls /user/hadoop/output, ofcourse because of error so it dont have output folder

Comment: Try the example in this: http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core/MapReduceTutorial.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found solution!! see this post- [yarn shows data nodes id/name as localhost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30468637/hadoop-yarn-node-list-shows-slaves-as-localhost-localdomainsomenumber-connect)

```
Call From localhost.localdomain/127.0.0.1 to localhost.localdomain:56148 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused;
```

Both master and slaves were having host names of localhost.localdomain in /etc/hostname.
I changed host names  of slaves to slave1 and slave2. That worked.
Thank you everyone for your time.

@kate make sure etc/hostname in namenode and datanodes are not set to localhost. Just type ~# hostname in terminal to see. You can set a new hostname by the same command.

My master and workers or slaves'  /etc/hosts looks like this-

```
127.0.0.1    localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4
#127.0.1.1    localhost
192.168.111.72  master
192.168.111.65  worker1
192.168.111.66  worker2
```

hostname of worker1

```
hduser@worker1:/mnt/hdfs/datanode$ cat /etc/hostname 
worker1
```

and worker2

```
hduser@worker2:/usr/local/hadoop/logs$ cat /etc/hostname 
worker2
```

Also, probably you don't want to have "hadoop" hostname with loopback interface. i.e.

```
127.0.0.1 localhost hadoop
```

Check this point (1) in https://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/ConnectionRefused.

Thank you.

Comment: Sr, but would you mind detail abt content in your etc/hostname (slaves and master) that made ur word count work, pls? still not understand.

Answer (score 0):

**FIREWALL ISSUE:**

> java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused

This error might be due to firewall issues. Do this in terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install iptables-persistent
sudo iptables -L
sudo iptables-save > /usr/iptables-backup/iptables.v4.rules
```

Check whether the file is created before continuing (since this will be used to restore firewall if something goes wrong).

Now, flush iptable rules (i.e. stop firewall):

```
sudo iptables -F
```

Now try,

```
sudo iptables -L
```

This command should return no rules. Now, try to run your map/reduce job.

**Note:** If you want to restore iptables to previous condition, type this in terminal:

`sudo iptables-restore < /usr/iptables-backup/iptables.v4.rules`

Comment: Sorry, but first I checked the list rule : iptables --list 
It just has 3 rules :

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination  .

But after follow ur answer, it has more than that: 

Is that should be ur mean?? (Need to ask first before I apply this to other nodes)

Comment: It means your `firewall is disabled`. After you have finished this on namenode system, try running the wordcount job. If the error persists, try this method on all datanodes and then execute the wordcount job.

Comment: I tried this on all namenode and datanodes, but still that error. When I checked ports with : "netstat -a|egrep 'Proto|LISTEN' " ; it list all ports are listenning. And found that no port 53245 (the one was in log error). And also in config file (hdfs,mapred,yarn,core-site) dont have any entry has this port. I wonder where this port 53245 come from??