# Hadoop yarn node list shows slaves as localhost.localdomain:#somenumber. connection refuse exception

Tags: hadoop

I have got connection refuse exception from localhost.localdomain/127.0.0.1 to localhost.localdomain:55352 when trying to run wordcount program. 
yarn node -list gives

```
hduser@localhost:/usr/local/hadoop/etc/hadoop$ yarn node -list
15/05/27 07:23:54 INFO client.RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at master/192.168.111.72:8040
Total Nodes:2
         Node-Id         Node-State Node-Http-Address   Number-of-Running-Containers
localhost.localdomain:32991         RUNNING localhost.localdomain:8042                             0
localhost.localdomain:55352         RUNNING localhost.localdomain:8042                             0
```

master /etc/hosts:

```
127.0.0.1    localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4
#127.0.1.1    ubuntu-Standard-PC-i440FX-PIIX-1996
192.168.111.72  master
192.168.111.65  slave1
192.168.111.66  slave2

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

slave /etc/hosts:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost.localdomain localhost
#127.0.1.1      ubuntu-Standard-PC-i440FX-PIIX-1996
192.168.111.72  master
#192.168.111.65  slave1
#192.168.111.66  slave2

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

What I understood is master is wrongly trying to connect to slaves on localhost. Please help me resolve this. Any suggestion is appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Here](https://github.com/apache/hadoop/blob/branch-2.6.0/hadoop-yarn-project/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-server/hadoop-yarn-server-nodemanager/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/yarn/server/nodemanager/containermanager/ContainerManagerImpl.java#L476) is the code how `NodeManager` builds the `NodeId`:

```
private NodeId buildNodeId(InetSocketAddress connectAddress,
  String hostOverride) {
  if (hostOverride != null) {
    connectAddress = NetUtils.getConnectAddress(
      new InetSocketAddress(hostOverride, connectAddress.getPort()));
  }
  return NodeId.newInstance(
    connectAddress.getAddress().getCanonicalHostName(),
    connectAddress.getPort());
}
```

`NodeManager` tries to get the canonical hostname from the binding address, `localhost` will be gotten by given address `127.0.0.1`.

So in your case, on the slave host, `localhost.localdomain` is the default host name for address `127.0.0.1`, and the possible solution might be changing the first line of `/etc/hosts` on your slaves respectively to:

```
  127.0.0.1  slave1 localhost.localdomain localhost
```

and

```
  127.0.0.1  slave2 localhost.localdomain localhost
```

Comment: appreciate very much for sharing this. However, Hadoop wiki https://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/ConnectionRefused recommends not to map hostname in 127.0.0.1/1.1. 
"Check that there isn't an entry for your hostname mapped to 127.0.0.1 or 127.0.1.1 in /etc/hosts (Ubuntu is notorious for this) "

Changing hostname in /etc/hostname which was set to localhost.localdomain for both slaves and master worked for me.  Anyway thanks for the insight.